# find string and append contents in new file

Tags: bash

Can any one help with bash shell script for below requirement?. 
Create one new file called "file.txt" and search for the file containing first line starts with "Format" and put the whole content of that file in new file "file.txt" .
This has to be done For all files in current directory so that appended result gets generated in new file.

Comment: So where is your code please?

Comment: Edited my ques, can you help me in writing the script ?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and free coding services (or exam writing) are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -Ens '^sometxt' * | awk -F: ' $2 == 1 { print $1 }' | xargs echo >> file.txt
```

Use grep and enable regular expression with -E. Also enable line number output with -n and the removal of error messages to output. Search for sometxt and parse the output through getting the file name as $1 (the first : delimited piece of data) and the count the second. If the line number ($2) is equal to one, then pipe the file name through xargs and cat the file out to file.txt